# error in arima : seasonal must be a list with a component 'order'

Tags: r, time-series, arima, autocorrelation

I am currently working on a univariate time series. I have two questions :

1/ First, I would like to cut it in sub-periods in order to best modelise this series in a linear frame, but do not know with what methodology (using ACF, or PACF coefficients ?). Which one do you recommend ?

2/ Second, I get an error when fitting the ARIMA(3,1,3)(2,1,2)12 model (a model suggested by R when i used the auto.arima function). How could I fix it ?

Here is my code :

```
 armaselect(prod,max.p=15,max.q=15,nbmod=10)
 fit1<-arima(prod,order=c(3,1,3), list(order(c(2,1,2)), period=12)) 
 fit1
 coeftest(fit1)
 acf(fit1$residuals,lag.max=36)
```

Here is the error message I get :

```
 Error in arima(prod, order = c(3, 1, 3), list(order(c(2, 1, 2)), period = 12)) : 
    'seasonal' doit être une liste possédant une composante 'order'
```

Here is the structure of my dataset for reproducibility :

```
    structure(list(date = c("2022-11", "2022-10", "2022-09", "2022-08", 
                           "2022-07", "2022-06"), production_brute_nucleaire = 
   c(22951.429, 
                                                                       
   21465.026, 19334.531, 19319.365, 19923.664, 21275.248)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                              
    6L), class = "data.frame")
```